# xgettext extracts wrong literals

Tags: java, xgettext

I use this to extract all string literals that need translation:

```
xgettext -o $@ -k"Localizer.get" $^ --from-code=utf-8
```

These should be extracted:

```
Localizer.get("Could not find the config file. (This should *not* happen!)")
```

These not:

```
SettingsWrapper.getString("date_format")
```

But both end up in my .pot file:

```
msgid "date_format"
msgstr ""
```

Is there some way to get this straight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [xgettext manual](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/xgettext-Invocation.html), `getString` is a default [keyword specification](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/xgettext-Invocation.html#index-g_t_002dk_0040r_007b_002c-_0040code_007bxgettext_007d-option_007d-186) for Java. You will need to disable default keywords and explicitly include any desired keyword specifications that were disabled which you want to enable. Try changing `-k"Localizer.get"` to `-k -k"Localizer.get"`.